# Error at WatiN.Core.IE.CreateNewIEAndGoToUri

Tags: .net, com, watin

I am doing Web tests with WatiN. i got following error:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 800706bf The remote procedure call failed and did not execute. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BF).   
at WatiN.Core.IE.CreateNewIEAndGoToUri(Uri uri, IDialogHandler logonDialogHandler, Boolean createInNewProcess)
at WatiN.Core.IE..ctor(String url)
```

my code is :

```
IE ie = new IE(URL);
Login login = new Login(ie);
login.LoginOneHR(userID, password));
CommonSetup01();
CommonSetup02();

ie.ForceClose();
IE ie_C = new IE(URL);
```

error occured at the last line.

if you know why or how to fix it, please help

Comment: Add a few seconds wait between closing and opening IE. Why do you close it anyway - just reuse it.

Comment: because, long time no interaction with IE, case will fail. my code is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, and a 2 second Thread.sleep fixed it for me.